# Inventory Widget Blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm creating a GUI inventory widget for the player, basically I have created the widget, it shows, I want to toggle the widget on and off, what I have now is, I can press the inventory key and it shows, on the A flip flop, but when for the B flip flop, it doesn't hide the inventory as it should be, although it prints the string, its not removing the widget as it should be, what should I add to my player blue print?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code on both sides of the flip-flop you are creating the widget, make sure the widget you are trying to hide is the one you created.

For that, remove the "Create Inventory Widget" node from the B part of the flip-flop and connect the "Set Visibility" node 'target' to the "Create Inventory Widget" 'return value' located in the A part of your flip-flop.

It's also recommended to save it as a variable to avoid confusion in your code if you ever need to something with the widget visibility again.